# Imprimir en el html desde JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Como puedo imprimir en un ul de HTML desde JavaScript una lista sin que se separe cada li con una ,

Al darle click al boton se imprime en un ul una serie de li segun el texto del input

```js
let nombres = ['FLDSMDFR', 'FLDSMDFR']

const li = (nombre) => `<li>${nombre}</li>`

function getValueInput() {
    nombres.push(document.getElementById('nombre').value)
    document.getElementById('lista').innerHTML = nombres.map(nombre => li(nombre))
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form>
            <label for="nombre"></label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
            <button type="button" onclick="getValueInput()">Click me!</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <ul id="lista">

    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza join('') al final de esta línea :

```
document.getElementById('lista').innerHTML = nombres.map(nombre => li(nombre)).join('')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió